# Using WSL for running Kafka

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have activated WSL on my Windows 10 machine, and installed Ubuntu.
Now I am trying to run Apache Kafka from source.

I have gradle installed in host machine.

In Ubuntu shell, I have cloned Kafka from github. At project root, when I run command 'gradle', I get error as:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

  > Could not create service of type CrossBuildFileHashCache using BuildSessionScopeServices.createCrossBuildFileHashCache().

Does it mean I need to install gradle in Ubuntu too?

Comment: You can build Kafka using `gradlew installAll`, you don't need to install anything

Comment: Running this command gives error:Command 'gradlew' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gradle' from deb gradle

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Comment: No, in the Kafka source directory, there's a gradlew executable, but sure, you can also install Gradle